# SSIS 2008 - How to log container error message on transaction rollback

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, error-logging, dts, ssis-2008

I've a new package containing a sequence container with a bunch of sql and data flow tasks inside. The intended behaviour is to create a transactional process over the container: if any task fail, then a rollback needs to be performed and the **error message** must be **logged for analysis**.

I set *TransactionOption* property of different objects as follow:

1. Package level : Supported
2. Container : Required
3. Each SQL or Data Flow Task : Supported
4. Enabled Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator

I've also introduced a duplicate primary key error.. and effectively works as expected: the rollback works fine.

The next step would be log into a SQL Server table the duplicate primary key error message. My questions are:

1. Which is the most appropiate place to catch the error message? OnError event of the containt? The PostExecute event of the container? Others?
2. On my investigation.. I'm loading the error message into a SSIS package variable. How can I pass it through a stored procedure input parameter?

Any comments/suggestions will be welcome.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The OnError event is the most appropriate place to handle errors.   Have you googled any EXECUTE SQL Task tutorials?   They all explain how to pass variables to parameters.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just use the native SSIS logging to a SQL Server table? There you just select the things you're interested in logging. Like OnError, OnTaskFailed, etc It'll be far less work and future maintenance than the road you appear to be going down

Comment: @billinkc --> +1 for sheeding light on the darkness. I digged into the approach you suggested and worked to the end I was investigating. Just turned on Logging on SQL Server at package level when the OnError event occurs. Many thanks.

Comment: My logging preference is: OnError, OnTaskFailed, OnWarning, OnPreExecute, OnPostExecute and OnInformation. Armed with those, I've been able to answer most of my SSIS related questions - how long did the package run, how long did the tasks run? What configurations were[n't] applied? What threw errors? What tasks actually failed? etc